# Can I insert a row or cell into an HTML table which can then be edited by clicking the cell?

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to HTML and Javascript.  I have created an HTML table that loads information from a database. The information loaded from the database is stored in cells that I've made editable.  I have a function that allows me to add empty rows to the table, which I then want to be able to edit by clicking on just like the rest of the table.  My goal in this is to edit the table and then use the Submit Changes button to update the database.

**My problem is that the cells loaded from the database are editable, but the empty cells inserted by the Add Row function aren't.  How can I modify these by clicking on them?**

```js
function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("eventTable");

  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
  var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
  var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
  cell1.innerHTML = "IT WORKED"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>View all Events </title>
  <link href="../static/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <h2> View all Events in the Database </h2>
  <h3> Display Events in MySQL Database </h3>
  <button type="button" id="changeEvents" class="center2">Submit Changes</button>
  <button type='button' onclick="addRow();" id="addEvent" class='center2'> Add Event</button>

  <TABLE id="eventTable" border="1" style="border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="4">
    <TR>
      <TH>ID</TH>
      <TH>Timestamp</TH>
      <TH>Filename</TH>
      <TH>Frequency</TH>
      <TH>Hostname</TH>
      <TH>Port</TH>
      <TH>Band</TH>
      <TH>Start Time</TH>
      <TH>End Time</TH>
      <TH>Delete</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true">
        <button type='button' id='delete0' 'class='center2 '> Delete Event </button></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The reason why the new cells are not editable is because you haven't set the `contenteditable` to `true`. Just like the first row each cell must have it set by this statement:

   ```
   cell.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
   ```
2. The last cell that has a delete button shouldn't be editable. `addRow()` now iterates `.insertCell()` 10 times and adds a `.delete` button on the 10<sup>th</sup> cell of every row. `delRow()` has been added as well.
3. Note the onevent attribute has been removed and replaced by an onevent property:

   ```
   // onevent attributes are stinky code smells
   <button onclick="addRow()"... 

   // onevent properties are far better
   document.querySelector('button').onclick = addRow;
   ```
4. Note: `.insertAdjacentHTML()` was used to make a `.delete` button on each row. You may see similar action done by `.innerHTML`. Try using the former because it does not destroy when rendering HTML while `.innerHTML` does.
5. Note: The table is registered to the click event and listens specifically for any clicks on any `.delete` button. Because the new `.delete` buttons did not exist when the page loaded, they cannot be registered for events such as `click'. So any dynamically created elements needs an ancestor element (parent, grandparent, document, window, etc) to listen for events.

   ```js
   const table = document.getElementById("eventTable");

   document.getElementById('addEvent').onclick = addRow;
   table.onclick = delRow;

   function delRow(e) {
     if (e.target.matches('.delete')) {
       let row = e.target.closest('tr');
       row.remove();
     }
   }

   function addRow() {
     let row = table.insertRow(1);
     for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       let cell = row.insertCell(i);
       if (i === 9) {
         cell.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<button type='button' class='center2 delete'> Delete Event </button>`);
         break;
       }
       cell.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
     }
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">

   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>View all Events </title>
     <link href="../static/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>

   <body>
     <h2> View all Events in the Database </h2>
     <h3> Display Events in MySQL Database </h3>
     <button type="button" id="changeEvents" class="center2">Submit Changes</button>
     <button type='button' id="addEvent" class='center2'> Add Event</button>

     <TABLE id="eventTable" border="1" style="border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="4">
       <TR>
         <TH>ID</TH>
         <TH>Timestamp</TH>
         <TH>Filename</TH>
         <TH>Frequency</TH>
         <TH>Hostname</TH>
         <TH>Port</TH>
         <TH>Band</TH>
         <TH>Start Time</TH>
         <TH>End Time</TH>
         <TH>Delete</TH>
       </TR>
       <TR>
         <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
         <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
         <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
         <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
         <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
         <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
         <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
         <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
         <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
         <TD>
           <button type='button' class='center2 delete'> Delete Event </button></TD>
       </TR>
     </TABLE>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Insert a `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` in each `<td></td>` by doing a:

`cell1.innerHTML = '<div contenteditable="true"></div>'`

Comment: No, I want to have the cells automatically be editable when I add a row from the webpage, I don't want to have to go back into the code after I've already opened the page.

Comment: I made a change.  TD elements are not contenteditable by themselves, they need to have a SPAN or DIV container to allow editing.

Comment: They actually are contenteditable by themselves.  The "<TD contenteditable="true">" code at the bottom of my post works to make the cells editable.  My issue is when I use insertRow and insertCell to add a new row, those cells aren't editable, and I want to change that.

Comment: It's not cross-browser compatible with IE.

Comment: If you insist, you can do: `cell1.setAttribute("contentEditable", true)`